# Use lithium ion car jumpstarter to charge netbook?

Tags: lithium-ion, charger, laptop, jumper

I have a Gooloo car jump starter pack. 
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B06X9R8QSY

Can I use it to charge a small Gateway Nav50 netbook? 
What kind of adapter would I need?

I suppose I could use this:
https://www.amazon.ca/Cigarette-Lighter-Adaptor-Battery-portable/dp/B019LPOTVA
plus any DC to AC inverter, and then plug in the netbook's AC to DC wall wart adapter, but ideally I would like to plug the netbook's 12V input more directly to the 12V output of the Gooloo jumper pack.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Questions about the usage of consumer products were long ago ruled to be off-topic here.  This is largely because, as here, the asker cannot give engineering-level specifications of the devices in question.  The pack might be designed to interface with a vehicle electrical system, but that does not mean it outputs 12 volts.  And there is no indication given of what the netbook requires; computer to "charger" interfaces are often non-trivial today.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware that it was off topic. Is there a general place that inquirers are sent to, to discuss such issues?
The product page does indicate a 2.5mm 12V output port on the jumper pack. I had visions of a cable that would plug into that, and into the laptop. Perhaps wishful thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of the cable to cigarette lighter to AC/DC converter to wall wart to laptop would work, but you are right - that is a lot of connections. [This cable](https://www.amazon.ca/GOOLOO-Cigarette-Lighter-Adaptor-Compressor/dp/B0777NXMSV/ref=pd_sim_263_5/145-5328723-5320916?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B0777NXMSV&pd_rd_r=530a6e3b-36ba-11e9-a62e-358d4c5f0879&pd_rd_w=APN7i&pd_rd_wg=wfMkr&pf_rd_p=29a85b27-a36a-4f8d-94ca-61aa962c5f39&pf_rd_r=WDC91HXTT46W99KG6FG9&psc=1&refRID=WDC91HXTT46W99KG6FG9) would also be suitable for that application, using the 12V output on the side of the GOOLOO. That 12V/10A port should not hurt your laptop, but I would be very hesitant to use the port that is for jumping your car - that has some serious power capable of coming out of it.

The best cable would be something going from the 12V/10A output on the GOOLOO straight to your netbook. From the looks of [this charger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075CXZS4K), your netbook has a 5.5mm connector. You would have to figure out the dimensions of the GOOLOO adapter (first link). From the questions/comments on the GOOLOO charger page itself, someone states it is a 5.5mm adapter (same as your laptop), but it's up to you if you want to trust that.

You could give [this cable a try](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DX6ZUBM), and see if it works! If that cable doesn't work, you'll either need to look for a cable with both of the correct connections, or if you are electrically savvy, make your own connector by hacking the GOOLOO adapter and a netbook charging cable.

Comment: The problem here is that you are making unbacked *guesses* - about what the power pack does, and about what the netbook will accept.  The high current "12v" output is almost certainly *not* 12 volts, except at a specific point on the charge/load curve, for example, because the current rating is too high for it to be likely that there is active power conversion going on in there.  This site is about engineering from *facts* - facts which are missing in this case.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I see. For my edification, what would be a better response? Since neither the user nor the product seem to have engineering documentation, should the question just remain unanswered/removed?

Comment: Indeed, off topic questions should generally not be answered.  The mission of stack exchange sites is *not* to satisfy all curiosities (there's a whole rest of the Internet for that) but rather to handle only the things which can be handled in their unique and *intentionally narrow* format.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Understood, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Thank you for your ideas ConcernedHobbit, and for your guidance on the discussion, chris-stratton . I will consider the question answered,and appreciate your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

So that double-ended [male to male cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DX6ZUBM) ended up not doing anything. It plugged in  okay to the charger and the netbook, but the netbook did not charge from it.

I also tried the [cigarette lighter adapter](https://www.amazon.ca/GOOLOO-Cigarette-Lighter-Adaptor-Compressor/dp/B0777NXMSV), plus a cigarette lighter power inverter, which I plugged the netbook's wall-wart charging cable into, and that worked for charging the netbook. So, I have a pretty cheap solution and am happy.

Thanks for your help!!